# Print string with all vowels replaced bu underscore - java

Tags: java, string

New to java... here is code. Works, but prints to many instances.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class FunWithLoopsStrings3
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String input;
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter String ");

for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ )
{
 String upperCaseInput = input.toUpperCase();     
 System.out.print(upperCaseInput.replaceAll("[AEIOU]", "_") );
}
}
}
```

example output: __SY__SY__SY__SY (for input of "easy"). 
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the for loop you want to replace it only once right... its printing `input.length` times... 
just do this

`String upperCaseInput = input.toUpperCase();

 System.out.print(upperCaseInput.replaceAll("[AEIOU]", "_") );`

Comment: Instructions require to be in "for" loop. Thank you for the input.

Comment: @C.Bush are you sure.. can you paste the instruction here please?

Comment: Write a Java test program that reads a String from the user and then prints the following:

Only the uppercase letters in the string.
Every second letter in the string.
The string with all the vowels replaced with an underscore.
The number of vowels in the string.
The positions of all the vowels in the string.
 

This program should be contained in a single main method. Each of the print requirements above should be implemented in a separate loop. At least one of the loops must use while, the remainder may use for.

Comment: @C.BushI think they meant each operation.. but i dont think it is necessary

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep searching.